# c# - How to get the amount of memory available for my application

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I found out that I can read the available physical memory by the
ComputerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory Property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.totalphysicalmemory.aspx

But is there any way to find out the memory that is actually available for my
application.
So, that for example, I can react if I'm running out of memory.

Is that possible?
Or is that just bad practice.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What will you do if you detect such a thing?  Physical memory and available heap are two very different things.  The garbage collector takes care of this in .NET, not you.  And it's a generational memory model - which generation is the issue?  I would not pursue this line of thinking.

Comment: Define "available". Also read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when about to run out of memory (getting the amount of "free physical memory")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478216/detecting-when-about-to-run-out-of-memory-getting-the-amount-of-free-physical)

Comment: ok, lets give you some more details...I want to find out how much memory there is available, so that I can optimize based on that data. So that I can try to not load too much data into memory, so that the system does not swap and so performance slows down

Comment: Don't try and sub optimize how the OS allocates memory. What specific performance problem do you have?

Comment: I receive huge files, then I load their data into memory and later send the data into a database. I want to optimize how much data I load into memory before I send it to the database.

I want to have, let's say a good number, about how much memory is available for my application (in general). So that I can optimize how much data I load into memory to get good performance.

Comment: Really you have an app constrained by physical memory when 8GB is memory is about $100.   You are running out of real memory before you run out of contiguous memory?   You will run out of contiguous memory way way short of 8GB.

Comment: Yes, I may run out of memory on some systems. but I don't know if it is physical memory or contiguous memory, that's why I was asking.
I'm looking for the best way to optimize. I only want to load as much in memory as it is good for performance. At some point it just gets slow because it starts to swap memory. I want to avoid that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the [Eric Lippert article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx) you'll hit this important paragraph:

> An “out of memory” error almost never happens because there’s not
>   enough storage available; as we’ve seen, storage is disk space, and
>   disks are huge these days. Rather, an “out of memory” error happens
>   because the process is unable to find a large enough section of
>   contiguous unused pages in its virtual address space to do the
>   requested mapping.

There is no way to know if there are contiguous unused pages available.

The best thing you can do is die gracefully when you have an "Out of Memory" exception.